# One to one relationship doesn't work in my Spring Boot back-end

Tags: spring, spring-boot, backend, relationship, one-to-one

I'm developing an ecommerce backend in Spring boot. There is a 1:1 relationship between the two entities `Order` and `Payment`. At first, I create a `Payment` (with `order` field null), when the payment is succesful (suppose always in this case), I create the order related to the payment created. The problem is that the `Order` entity is created but it isn't connected with the `Payment` entity because when I try to print the order in the PaymentService it says that the order is stil null for that payment (even if, in `createOrder` method, I did `payment.setOrder(o);` as shown below). Moreover, if from the database I try to delete the payment, it tells me that the payment could not be removed because it is connected to the order, but strangely, when I try to print the order of the payment that I have created, the result is null.

[image]

OrderService:

```
@Service
public class OrderService {
    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CartRepository cartRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PaymentRepository paymentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public Order createOrder (int paymentId, int userId, int cartId) {
        System.out.println("UserId: "+userId);
        System.out.println("Payment: "+paymentId);
        System.out.println("cartId: "+cartId);
        if(userRepository.existsById(userId)){
            System.out.println("Exists");}
        User user = userRepository.findById(userId);
        if(user==null){
            System.out.println("User is null");
        }
        Payment payment = paymentRepository.findById(paymentId);
        System.out.println("Payment: "+payment);
        Cart c = cartRepository.findById(cartId);
        Order o = new Order();
        o.setPayment(payment);
        o.setCart(c);
        o.setBuyer(user);
        Order justAdded = orderRepository.save(o);
        entityManager.refresh(justAdded);
        entityManager.refresh(o);
        payment.setOrder(o);
        entityManager.refresh(payment);
        return justAdded;
    }
}
```

OrderController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseEntity<Order> createOrder (@RequestParam(required = false) int paymentId,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false) int buyerId,
                                                    @RequestParam(required = false) int cartId){

            return new ResponseEntity<>(orderService.createOrder(paymentId, buyerId, cartId), HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

PaymentService:

```
@Service
public class PaymentService {

    @Autowired
    private PaymentRepository paymentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public Payment addPayment(Payment p) throws PaymentAlreadyExistsException, IncorrectCardNumberException, IncorrectCvvException{//
        if(paymentRepository.existsByCardNumber(p.getCardNumber())){
            throw new PaymentAlreadyExistsException();
        }
        if(p.getCardNumber().length()!=16){
            throw new IncorrectCardNumberException();
        }
        if(p.getCvv().length()!=3)
        {
            throw new IncorrectCvvException();
        }
        System.out.println("Sto salvando il pagamento: "+p);
        Order newOrder = new Order();
        newOrder.setPayment(p);
        Order justAdded=orderRepository.save(newOrder);
        entityManager.refresh(justAdded);
        p.setOrder(justAdded);


        return paymentRepository.save(p);
    }
```

PaymentController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/payments")
public class PaymentController {
    @Autowired
    private PaymentService paymentService;

    @PostMapping("/createPayment")//funziona
    public ResponseEntity<Payment> create(@RequestBody @Valid Payment payment){
        System.out.print("Sono in paymentController.");
        try {
            Payment added=paymentService.addPayment(payment);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(added, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (PaymentAlreadyExistsException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity(new ResponseMessage("Payment already exists!"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } catch (IncorrectCardNumberException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity(new ResponseMessage("Incorrect card number!"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } catch (IncorrectCvvException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity(new ResponseMessage("Incorrect CVV"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
}
}
```

Payment entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "payment", schema = "purchase")
public class Payment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "owner_name", nullable = true, length = 70)
    private String ownerName;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "owner_last_name", nullable = true, length = 70)
    private String ownerLastName;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "card_number", nullable = true, length = 16)
    private String cardNumber;

    @Basic
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)

    @Column(name = "expiration", nullable = true)
    private Date expiration;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "cvv", nullable = true, length = 3)
    private String cvv;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "total", nullable = true)
    private float total;


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "payment")
    private Order order;


}
```

Order entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Entity

@Table(name = "order", schema = "purchase")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Basic
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "order_time")
    private Date orderTime;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "buyer")
    private User buyer;



    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "payment_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Payment payment;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
    private Cart cart;
}
```

I have the following method in `PaymentService`:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)//
    public List<Payment> getAllPayments(){
        List<Payment> result = paymentRepository.findAll();
        for(Payment p: result){
            if(p.getOrder()==null)
            System.out.println("Order in payment is null");
        }
        return paymentRepository.findAll();
    }
```

And when I execute it (after having created a `Payment`, an `Order` and tried to connect them using the `createOrder` method),

> Order in payment is null

is printed, so the field `order` for that `Payment` is still null.

While, the `Order` oject is created in the following way in the database:
[image]

I've edited `createOrder` method, as suggested, in the following way, but the problem persists:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public Order createOrder (int paymentId, int userId, int cartId) throws PaymentDoesNotExistException{
        User user = userRepository.findById(userId);
        Payment payment = paymentRepository.findById(paymentId);
        if(payment == null)
        { throw new PaymentDoesNotExistException();
        }
        System.out.println("Payment: "+payment);
        Cart c = cartRepository.findById(cartId);
        Order o = new Order();
        o.setPayment(payment);
        o.setCart(c);
        o.setBuyer(user);
        payment.setOrder(o);
        orderRepository.save(o);
        return o;

    }
```

Comment: Please also show: Entities, how you invoke the endpoints(, output)

Comment: Whats with all the `refresh` calls? Those aren't needed. Your service methods seem overly complex and the interesting parts are missing from your question (your actual entities).

Comment: I've added the entities in my question. @M.Deinum

Comment: When doing `setPayment` on the order also set the `Order` on the `Payment` and just save the `Order`. That should save everything that is needed. Also stop using Lombok for `equals` and `hashCode` as it will create a wrong `equals` and `hashCode` for JPA.

Comment: I tried like you said (and edidted my question), but unfortunately the problem persists. @M.Deinum

Comment: You also need to add `cascade=ALL` to your `OneToOne` annotation on the `Order`.

Comment: Tanks, but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw couple of unwanted things. No need to call refresh. Just create child objects and save them first and then save the parent. Just a guidance here, make your own custom exceptions and messages.

```
    Payment payment = paymentRepository.findById(paymentId);
    if(payment == null)
    { throw Exception("Payment not found");}
    System.out.println("Payment: "+payment);
    Cart c = cartRepository.findById(cartId);
    Order o = new Order();
    o.setPayment(payment);
    o.setCart(c);
    o.setBuyer(user);
    orderRepository.save(o);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried like you said and edited my question, but the problem persists.

Comment: have you debugged and see if that payment is null?

Comment: I used a println in `getAllPayments()` method to check if the payment is null, and it turned out that the payment is null.

Comment: So see you have to first create one and then save it, after that add that to order via setPayment. That's why I told you to debug and see if there is a payment for that passed payment_id

Comment: I created and saved a `Payment` and then an `Order`, I added the payment to the order via setPayment. As a result, in `payment_id` there is the id of the `Payment` to which I want the `Order` to be connected to. Moreover, if from the database I try to delete that payment, it tells me that the payment could not be removed because it is connected to the order, but strangely, when I try to print the order of the payment that I have created, the result is null.

Comment: So it seems the reading part, check the id you pass from the code and check with a manual query on db

Comment: @Giovanna  if this worked you can accept the answer so in the future you will get better chances

Comment: It still prints null, but if I add this line of code `payment.setOrder(o);` to the answer that you gave me, the relation is created, so I think I can accept your answer

Comment: @Giovanna as a new user you wouldnt know how to accept an answer, on the top leftside of my answer, there is a check mark , if you click this it will go green. I was told this when I was new to StackOF, so passing down the info

Comment: Thanks! I did it, let me know if it appears to you

Comment: @Giovanna yes it appeared, welcome to stackoverflow too!